# GRASS GIS Plugin not loading in QGIS 3

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

When starting up QGIS 3.2.2 (also tested with 3.2.3), I get the following message in the "Plugins" Log Message Window:

```
2018-10-18T08:03:48     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\plugins\grassplugin7.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
2018-10-18T08:03:48     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/plugins/grassprovider7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\plugins\grassprovider7.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
2018-10-18T08:03:48     WARNING    Failed to load C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/plugins/grassrasterprovider7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\plugins\grassrasterprovider7.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
2018-10-18T08:03:48     INFO    Loaded mmqgis (package: mmqgis)
2018-10-18T08:03:50     INFO    Loaded Networks (package: networks)
2018-10-18T08:03:50     INFO    Loaded QuickOSM (package: QuickOSM)
2018-10-18T08:03:52     INFO    Loaded QuickMapServices (package: quick_map_services)
2018-10-18T08:03:52     INFO    Loaded DB Manager (package: db_manager)
2018-10-18T08:03:52     INFO    Loaded MetaSearch Catalog Client (package: MetaSearch)
2018-10-18T08:03:54     INFO    Loaded Processing (package: processing)
```

And sure enough, I cannot use the GRASS GIS Plugins. I also have QGIS 2.18.24 installed, the plugins are fully available there. Any idea what the issue might be?

**EDIT:**

I also tested with OSGeo4W Network Installer (64 bit), with the same result. Also note that `grassplugin7.dll`, `grassprovider7.dll` and `grassrasterprovider7.dll` are available in the folder C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\plugins

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Here are my MSVC++ Versions
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, this is slightly embarrassing but I'll post the answer here anyway in case someone is as blind as I was. Apparently, there are two QGIS executable files: `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin.exe` and `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin-g7.4.1.exe`. In Windows, when firing up a program via the Windwos startup button, it runs `qgis-bin.exe` by default and GRASS does not work. When you run `qgis-bin-g7.4.1.exe` however, it GRASS *works*.

<s>I'll show myself out</s>

Comment: no need to show yourself out.  over two years later and you've saved me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a faulty installation. I faced some plugin issue with OSGeo4W installation in windows OS whereas my Linux system is all good.

If there is not any specific reason to stick with 3.2.2, I would suggest to download and install the standalone version of QGIS 3.2.3-Bonn with GRASS 7.4.1.

Its running all fine in my Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I uninstalled both QGIS Versions 2.18.24 and 3.2.2 and installed 3.2.3 with GRASS 7.4.1. The issue persists... Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked if any of the previous dlls are sitting in the sytem like Appdata folder or so. Do a quick search to check if the DLLs are only on one place.

Comment: Also make sure the MSVC++ runtime is uptodate. I have experineced a lot of problems of dlll loading where the installed MSVC++ is different than which was used to comile the dlls. The MSVC++ that comes with the GRASS 7.4.1 should be fully compatible with GRASS dlls. Also make sure the Windows registry is not carrying a older/imcompatible MSVC++. DLLs are absolute pain now a days.

Comment: To your first question: I searched my entire Harddrive and found the dll's at two locations. Once for each QGIS Installation. For QGIS 2.18 it's locatated here `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins` while its located here `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\plugins` for QGIS 3.2.3.

Comment: To your second question: I've added my MSVC++ Versions in the original question: