# GRASS not working with QGIS 3.7

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osgeo4w

Like the author of [GRASS not working with QGIS 3.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6), I am unable to use GRASS plugins, with the error:

> This algorithm cannot be run :-( The specified GRASS 7 folder "C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\bin" does not contain a valid set of GRASS 7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check that the GRASS 7 folder is correctly configured

This applies whether or not I start QGIS using the *"QGIS Desktop 3.6.3 with GRASS 7.6.1"* option or not.

I do not have an option to specify the GRASS path in the `Settings > Option > Processing` menu.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this error is a bit tricky (In earlier versions there was a configuration option to set the path, but for some reasons that has been removed).

First find where your GRASS installation is under the QGIS folder. By default it will be:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass76
```

but you need to check and find the exact path.

Now start QGIS and click **Settings->Options** and go to the **Advanced** tab. Click the warning button "I will be careful", and then expand (click the small arrow) the **Processing -> Configuration** item. Scroll down to the **Grass7 Folder**. Now double click to edit that configuration variable, and set the correct path from your check above. Restart QGIS and you should have access to the GRASS commands.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the QGIS 3.4.4 version's GRASS tools work, or at least the r.water.outlet tool I was having trouble with.

You can download 8.4.4 from here:
https://qgis.org/downloads/

If anyone can make ALL the GRASS tools work in the Pi or Coruna versions please do.