# GRASS doesn't run on QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, windows-10

I've just installed qgis via OSGoe4W custom install on a brand new windows 10 machine.
in the desktop section of the install dialog I've selected grass 7.8.3-1
in libs section QGIS-GRASS-plugin7 for QGIS 3.14.16-3 as well as for QGIS ltr version 3.10.10-3

the installation ran without any troubles.

trying to run any GRASS function via processing toolbox returns the following error:
"`the specified GRASS 7 folder  "C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\bin" does not a valid set of GRASS 7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check that the GRASS 7 folder is correctly configured`"

searching StackExchange returned some promising results - like [GRASS not working with QGIS 3.7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326857/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-7) (and it's predecessor-article for QGIS 3.6 as well) where one user suggested tweaking QGIS settings via "`Settings -> Options -> Advanced -> Configuration`" and set the current Grass7 path explicitly.

but my problem is, that neither QGIS ltr/3.10 nor QGIS 3.14. do show a "GRASS Folder" entry in the Advanced Settings Editor - see the following screenshot:

[image]

so I do not have any option to identify the GRASS path in the same way as described in the before-mentioned posting.

the remarkable thing is that version 3.14. on mac osx looks different:
[image]

and ist works perfectly ...

Comment: The thing that worked for me was a comment by ewolf in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313724/grass-not-working-with-qgis-3-6 : "I use Windows 10, so in Windows Explorer: right click This PC, select Properties then Advanced system settings, then Advanced tab, then Environmental Variables. Click New... and enter "GISBASE" in Variable Name, and "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass78" in Variable Value [NOTE: your path may be different depending on the version of QGIS and/or GRASS you have]. Click OK and you should see the newly created variable added to the list"

Comment: @ Ian Turton: thx for this tip. i've removed everything which was related with QGIS from my machine and started from scratch. after a full reinstall with OSGeo4W. GRASS GIS 7.8.3-1, QGIS Desktop 3.14.16-2 @ Desktop and GRASS7 plugin for QGIS, GRASS plugin for QGIS (common) are active. now i can find the C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin-g7.exe file - and start QGIS with GRASS working fine